# I can't run shell commands on Linux through AVR sketch (Arduino Yun)

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-yun, linux, networking, tcpip

I'm a little confused with some Process.h methods.
I'm trying to run the command "nc 192.168.1.15 9911" to the Linux processor through a sketch.
The appropriate netcat listener is waiting on another computer. Arduino Yun is on the same network with thie computer via WiFi.

When I execute this command through SSH connection on Arduino Yun it works fine, but I can't figure out how it's done through a sketch.

This is my code:

```
#include <Process.h>

Process p;

void setup() {
   Bridge.begin();
   Serial.begin(9600);
   delay(2000);
   p.begin("nc");
   p.addParameter("192.168.1.15 9911");
   p.run();
   //while (!p.running()) {};

 }

 void loop() {
    if (p.available() > 0) {
    Serial.println("test");
 }
}
```

This code doesn't seem to work, p.available() nerver executes even if I send data packets.
I also tried **p.runShellCommand("nc 192.168.1.15 9911");** with no luck.

It seems that the commands never reach the Linux command line.

Any insights?

Comment: and does `Serial` print something at all? the examples for Yun have SerialUSB for Serial Monitor. https://github.com/arduino-libraries/Bridge/blob/master/examples/Process/Process.ino . and I would add parameters with two addParameter

Comment: Nothing at all. I did try this example long ago but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few things wrong with your program, some more obvious than others.

First, you have to put each parameter to your shell command in a separate `addParameter()` call. Otherwise it treats all the parameters as a single parameter and tries to connect you to an address of `192.168.1.15 9911` instead of to port 9911 of address 192.168.1.15.

Secondly you should use `runAsynchronously()` instead of `run()` otherwise your sketch blocks at that point until `nc` terminates. If that never happens then your sketch never gets to the point where it can read the data.

Here is an adaption of your sketch that works for me:

```
#include <Process.h>

Process p;

void setup() {
    Bridge.begin();
    Console.begin();
    p.begin("nc");
    p.addParameter("192.168.1.15");
    p.addParameter("9911");
    p.runAsynchronously();
}

void loop() {
    static uint32_t ts = millis();

    if (millis() - ts > 1000) {
        Console.println(millis());
        ts = millis();
    }

    if (p.running()) {
        while (p.available()) {
            Console.write(p.read());
        }
    } else {
        Console.println("Restarting process");
        delay(100);
        p.begin("nc");
        p.addParameter("192.168.1.15");
        p.addParameter("9911");
        p.runAsynchronously();
    }
}
```

It also re-runs `nc` if / when it terminates. There's also a "heartbeat" printing of millis() so that you can see the sketch is running.  It uses the console, not Serial, for its output, so SSH in to the Yun and `telnet localhost 6571` to view the output.

Comment: Although right now I don't need to implement the above code because things have changed, your answer solves the current question. Thanks.